# How to set interpreter binding mode in interpreter-setting.json in Zeppelin on k8s

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am running Zeppelin on k8s with interpreter binding mode set to isolated per user from the UI. However, sometimes the pod restarts and I lose the settings I had made from the UI. I know there is interpreter-settings.json to configure the interpreter settings but these properties are not available there. I found it in /conf/interpreter.json but changing that directly causes zeppelin to malfunction.